# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'DetailedResponse'

Tags: python, django, string, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

I have set up a `Jupyter Notebook` that connect my `Postgresql database`, call the datas within a table and apply a Machine Learning model from an API to these datas, but I keep getting a `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'DetailedResponse'`.

My Notebook is set up in 3 cells but I put them together below for clarity:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import json

conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('119.203.10.242', 5432, 'mydb', 'locq', 'Mypass***')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e)


natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='F76ugy8hv1s3sr87buhb7564vb7************'
)


classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', data_df_1.to_json())

print(json.loads(classes, indent=2))
```

And the full error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b6b7d122a500> in <module>()
      2 
      3 classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', data_df_1.to_json())
----> 4 print(json.loads(classes, indent=2))

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    310     if not isinstance(s, str):
    311         raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, not {!r}'.format(
--> 312                             s.__class__.__name__))
    313     if s.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
    314         raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",


TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'DetailedResponse'
```

I've tried so many things to get there and now I'm totally stuck and I can't find a way to fix this or I might just don't understand the code enough to fix it.

Please help.

**EDIT**

The API generate a header within the output so I get an error when I try to serialize, is there a way to remove the header?

output:

```
TypeError: {'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'", 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Expires': '0', 'X-Backside-Transport': 'OK OK', 'X-DP-Transit-ID': 'gateway01-1254538093', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-global-transaction-id': '7ecac92c59876gfjbb6d', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;', 'X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID': 'gateway01-125765453', 'X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT': '19', 'X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency': '498', 'Content-Length': '868', 'Date': 'Thu, 23 May 2019 17:15:58 GMT', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1'} is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familliary with this library, but i will try to fix your problem.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import json

conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('119.203.10.242', 5432, 'mydb', 'locq', 'Mypass***')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e)


natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='F76ugy8hv1s3sr87buhb7564vb7************'
)


classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('7818d2s519-nlc-1311', data_df_1.to_json())

data_dict = classes._to_dict() # this will returns dict
data_dict.pop('headers', None) # remove headers key
print(data_dict) # This shows you dictionary in terminal
# if you want to serialize this and save on disk, you should make json serialization for example.
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
print(json_data) # this shows your string(json) in terminal
```

Try this way also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just tried to add the code at the bottom but I get this new error now: `AttributeError: 'DetailedResponse' object has no attribute 'json'`

Comment: I updated my answer. please print json_data also, and let us information about it

Comment: Thanks , just tried and getting this now: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`

Comment: Yes. I updated answer and it works I think. See final version (It will returns dictionary).

Comment: Nevermind, I did this and It worked: `print(data_dict)`

Comment: Fine, I updated answer also which covers more details. good luck.

Comment: I tried to make a serialization but the problem is that the API generate a Header in the output and I get this as an error because of the header, see edited question.

Comment: what happens when you write `json.dumps(data_dict)` ?

Comment: Thanks so much it works. I don't know why but If I just do `print(json_data)` without the `json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)`  it returns the same thing as if I had this code `data_dict.pop('headers', None)
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)`..

Comment: I updated my code (Check it). Just `print(data_dict)` after make `.pop()` from dict. `data_dict` is dict object. `json_data` is string (json) object. They are different objects, but containing same data.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to make you feel like I'm asking to much but the prediction is being applied to all my description datas instead of a single unique prediction for each descriptions in my table. I will ask another question and send you the link here if you don't mind answering to this one too, just let me know.

Comment: I helped you to fix problem, but in general I am not familiar with this library. make new question and people will help you. good luck !

Answer (score 1):

*I would add a comment but I do not have the reputation yet*

json.loads() takes a string and it doesn't seem your classes variable is a string. You may have to do str(classes) to use it's string representation

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, really appreciated! I will try this out now.

Comment: It works thanks so much!! But the results don't seem to be in json since they are in single quotes..

Comment: Nevermind, the API added headers to the response! Thanks again!

Comment: I actually think @gachdavit answer is safer. trace a bit through the [code](https://github.com/IBM/python-sdk-core/blob/c2bc8e41d9ec836c0118ffbc45cd0522aaa5c341/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py) and since it is using requests the response should be easily parsed as json